# How can I override a default file extension for Notepad++?

Tags: objective-c, notepad++

I want to open iOS objective-c files in Notepad++ (with a .m extension) and have it designated as an Objective-C file. In settings --> style configurator, I know that I can add a "user ext." (m) for Objective-C. The problem is that Matlab already uses the .m extension as the default extension field, which can't be edited. Is there a file I can access to change this?

Comment: Voting to close, as I believe this question belongs on http://superuser.com (will be automatically migrated, when it receives enough votes).

Comment: @fireeyedboy: [nope](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: Hm, if the FAQ says otherwise, I hope someone cleans the close votes before it's actually moved.

Comment: Notepad++ falls in the "tools commonly used by programmers" bin mentioned in the FAQ.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Notepad++ doesn't list `.h`, `.m` and `.mm` files as Objective-C files (`.mm` is Objective-C++) by default for some reason.

You can modify your `langs.xml` file to tell Notepad++ to associate those extensions with Objective-C. Open the file `%AppData%\Notepad++\langs.xml`, and scroll down to the following area:

```xml
<Language name="objc" ext="" commentLine="//" commentStart="/*" commentEnd="*/">
    <Keywords name="instre1">if else switch case default break goto return for while do continue typedef sizeof NULL self super nil NIL</Keywords>
    <Keywords name="instre2">interface implementation protocol end private protected public class selector encode defs</Keywords>
    <Keywords name="type1">void struct union enum char short int long double float signed unsigned const static extern auto register volatile id Class SEL IMP BOOL</Keywords>
    <Keywords name="type2">oneway in out inout bycopy byref</Keywords>
</Language>
```

Then add `h m mm` to the `ext` attribute:

```xml
<Language name="objc" ext="h m mm" commentLine="//" commentStart="/*" commentEnd="*/">
    <Keywords name="instre1">if else switch case default break goto return for while do continue typedef sizeof NULL self super nil NIL</Keywords>
    <Keywords name="instre2">interface implementation protocol end private protected public class selector encode defs</Keywords>
    <Keywords name="type1">void struct union enum char short int long double float signed unsigned const static extern auto register volatile id Class SEL IMP BOOL</Keywords>
    <Keywords name="type2">oneway in out inout bycopy byref</Keywords>
</Language>
```

Then restart Notepad++.

If editing the `langs.xml` file in your `%AppData%\Notepad++` folder doesn't work, you'll have to open the one in `%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++` instead. Make sure to back up the original in case you mess up somewhere.