# All R script being styled as comment

Tags: r, formatting, notepad++, comments

I'm having trouble with Notepad++ on Windows 7 - it's styling all my codes as comments (i.e. all code appears green).

[image: help me]

I've turned on "view all characters" and there doesn't appear to be any hidden # to make it happen.

I don't have admin access on my machine, so I cannot update to a newer version of windows, nor can I easily change around any built in settings, but I can ask for help if necessary.

Many thanks,
Aodhán

Comment: Are you married to using Notepad++ to edit? SublimeText & RStudio probably have better code highlighting. I assume the code runs as intended, and this is just an issue of appearance in your editor?

Comment: Hi Michael, I wouldn't say I'm in a til-death-do-we-part situation but I have to go to IT to get any new programs installed (a change for me). I am very used to Notepad++ and use it when I'm scripting in other languages, like python (or sometimes just making notes for myself), as I find it easier to use a single program for all of them. I've heard of SublimeText before but I haven't had a chance to try it out, something I must correct. For some reason, I don't like RStudio very much.

Comment: I'll also suggest Atom which I just started using (which is completely free, as opposed to ST which is "free"), with the caveat that R highlighting is a bit more distal: https://discuss.atom.io/t/syntax-highlighting-for-r-language/12508

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, turns out the problem is that REBOL shares a file extension with R and it was interpreting the file as a REBOL file. This can be changed in Language->R->R

[image]

I'll update this when I find out how to make this the default.

EDIT: I couldn't find a way of doing this inside Notepad++ but the following [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043544/how-can-i-override-a-default-file-extension-for-notepad) did let me work it out. I edited `%AppData%\Notepad++\langs.xml` and made the following two changes:

1:

> ```
> <Language name="rebol" ext="r reb" commentLine=";" commentStart="" commentEnd=""\>
> ```

Becomes (getting rid of the r in ext = "r reb"):

> ```
> <Language name="rebol" ext="reb" commentLine=";" commentStart="" commentEnd=""\>
> ```

2:

> ```
> <Language name="r" ext="r s splus" commentLine=";" commentStart="" commentEnd=""\>
> ```

Becomes (adding R in ext = "r s splus"):

> ```
> <Language name="r" ext="r s splus R" commentLine=";" commentStart="" commentEnd=""\>
> ```

This was a permenant solution to my problem, as I don't intend on using REBOL (and have never encountered the language before this issue). If I do have to use it I can still use the formatting by saving them as .reb files.

Comment: merge this custom theme for monokai set and it [works](https://github.com/DheerajAgarwal/Monokai_RTheme_Npp)